# Incrementing the lvalue of a pointer to char?

Tags: c, pointers, char

My question is simple:

Say you have this:

```
char *chrptr = "junk";
```

Imagine at the time, `*chrptr` would point at `j`. Is there a way to increment the current character `j` to the next character which, in this case would be `k`? I don't want to go to the next character, I want to increment the current-pointed to character.

I'm new to C, and what I tried: `(*chrptr)++` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your edit, it seems like you want to modify the string, you can't do that with a constant string, actually you can but that behaviour is undefined. So you need to change the definition to a non-constant array of characters:

```
//This initializes a 5 element array including the null byte at the end
char chrptr[] = "junk";
//now you can modify that
chrptr[0]++;
//or equivalently 
chrptr[0] +=1;
chrptr[0] = chrptr[0]+1;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that syntax though. Since it is not something commonly seen, it will only confuse the reader. A better way would in my opinion be to write `chrptr[0] = chrptr[0]+1;`, which will result in the same machine code.

Comment: I've added a few other, but it's not that uncommon and IMHO it's the most concise form.

Comment: @Lundin why would you want to say `chrptr[0]` twice? `anything += 1` reads as "increment anything by 1" and is very understandable at first glance

Comment: @Kos I think the += 1 is fine too. The [0]++ strikes me as potentially dangerous, because real code will look like `chrptr[i]++`. From there, the step is not far to `chrptr[i++]` which will compile just fine, but mean something completely different. Using the ++ operator together with other operators is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *chrptr = "junk";
```

This code isn't really good. String literals like "junk" are pointers to read-only memory. You're not supposed to ever modify them. So either say:

```
const char* chrptr = "junk"; // pointer to a const; no modifications
```

or (in your case):

```
char chrArray[] = "junk";
```

This creates a 5-element array of characters on the stack, initializes it with "junk" (plus the null terminator). Now you're free to modify it:

```
chrArray[0] ++;
(*chrArray) ++;
```

---

*(Some leftover remarks)*

> I'm new to c, but things such as (*chrptr)++ don't work.

They *do* work, but differently. Let me sum this up:

- `chrptr` is a value of type pointer-to-char.
- `*chrptr` is a value of type char, because the pointer has been dereferenced.

Both of these happen to be "l-values" (= actual objects), so you can modify them:

- `++ chrptr` increments the pointer by one (= advances the pointer one object forward)
- `++ *chrptr` increments the char by one (= changes `'a'` into `'b'`).

(Before, `++*chrptr` didn't work for you because the string was in read-only section of memory. If you had pointed to it using `const char*` not `char*`, you'd get a helpful compile error instead of unexpected runtime behaviour.)

---

Also note:

In case of a simple statement, `++*chrptr;` is equivalent to `(*chrptr)++;`. The operator order is important (dereference, then increment).

OTOH, `*chrptr++` is increment-then-dereference because of the [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). If not sure about precedence, add parentheses.

Comment: Oh, I see your edit. Let me expand, your problem is something different

Comment: Yeah, my example was really bad. Sorry for wasting your time by asking a badly worded question.

Comment: @fayyazkl Ahh obviously yes, thanks! C#, what have you done to me... :(

Comment: Yeah that happens. Me too - when coming back to c after doing c# a while

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to dereference the pointer again using the dereference operator `*`.

You simply need to do `chrptr++` to advance the character pointer in memory.

**Update**

You can wrap a `while` loop around to search for the character.

```
char *chrptr = "junk";
char search = 'k';

while (*chrptr) {
  if (*chrptr == search)
    printf("%c\n", *chrptr);
  chtptr++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was really bad. That's not what I meant -- please read my updated example.

Answer (score 1):

See this (*chrptr)++; works fine but this will increment the first character of the array pointed by chrptr.
In your case you are using the statement like

> char *chrptr = "junk";

Here chrptr is pointing to a const char array so on using (*chrptr)++; it will increment not reflect the changes in the string.

But if you use the code like this way (http://codepad.org/FJMB1ryv) :--

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char a[]="yogendra";
char *y=a;//(char*)"junk";
(*y)++;
cout<<y<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

you (*y)++ will work.Hoping this will help you. Good luck:)